# How to exit from Python using a Tkinter Button?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, exit, tk-toolkit

To start off, let me show you my code:

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
import time
import sys

def endProgam():
    raise SystemExit
    sys.exit()

top = Tkinter.Tk()
B = Tkinter.Button(top, text = "Hello", command = endProgam)
B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

As you can see under `endProgram()` I have tried 2 types of exit commands, both do not work. I never used them together, I was just trying to show what methods I have used so far. These methods were methods I found here and on other websites, but if I try either, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sa'id\Documents\Learning Programming\Python\Tkinter Tuts.py", line 22, in <module>
    top.mainloop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1070, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1488, in __call__
    raise SystemExit, msg
SystemExit
```

I can't seem to find a fix to this and I was hoping maybe someone here could help me. If you need any more details I will gladly provide what you need.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using your code as shown (with Python 2.7.8 on Win7-x64). How are you running the script?

Comment: Are you saying you get the "raise SystemExit" error message even when you call `sys.exit()`?

Comment: @martineau, I am also running 2.7(.8) and I am using Sublime Text 3 with SublimeREPL to run my Python programs. The question has been answered, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @BryanOakley, Yes, both times I get the same errors. It was answered, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two functions you should use to *quit* a window:

- `destroy()`
- `quit()`

Here you have the code using one of the two:

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
import time
import sys

def endProgam():
    # top.quit()
    top.destroy()        

top = Tkinter.Tk()

B = Tkinter.Button(top, text = "Hello", command = endProgam)
B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, `top.destroy()` worked but `top.quit()` only half worked, in the sense that SublimeREPL was terminated but the window was still there. Again, thanks.